VSCode: pyspark runs fine when using "run python file" option. But throws error when using "run code" option
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Datacamp Pyspark Tutorial").config("spark.memory.offHeap.enabled","true").config("spark.memory.offHeap.size","10g").getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.csv('datacamp_ecommerce.csv',header=True,escape="\"")
df.show(5,0)


When I run using the option Run Python file (shown in the image above), it successfully displays the output in the TERMINAL tab of VSCode.
But when I use the first option Run Code (shown in image above), it throws the following error in the OUTPUT tab of VSCode.


[Running] python -u "c:\VSCode_PyProjects\VSCode_PysparkProj\venv\test.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\VSCode_PyProjects\VSCode_PysparkProj\venv\test.py", line 1, in 
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyspark'

Remarks:

As shown in the image below, the env folder contains pyspark.
I have python, spark, pyspark, and java installed on Windows-10 using this post.
I've also installed popular Code Runner extension in VSCode.

Question: Why the code works fine with Run Python File, but not with Run Code option. What I may be missing here, and how we can fix the issue?

